# How to update account loaded with AccountInfo

Tags: anchor, solana-program, accountinfo

For some migration purpose I need to load a pda account with `AccountInfo` , reallocate and update the fields. I am able to make other parts right got stuck updating/modifying account data. Transaction is succeeding but account field is not getting updated.

Here is a minimal code example.

```
let collection_account: &mut AccountInfo = &mut ctx.accounts.collection_info;
        
let mut data:&[u8] = &** collection_account.try_borrow_mut_data().unwrap();
let mut collection_info: CollectionInfo = CollectionInfo::try_deserialize(&mut data).unwrap();

collection_info.version = CollectionInfo::VERSION;
```

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(collection_address: Pubkey)]
pub struct CollectionInfoMigration<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [ COLLECTION_INFO_SEED, collection_address.as_ref() ],
        bump,
    )]
    pub collection_info: AccountInfo<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try deserializing using `anchor_lang::Account::try_from` and creating a mutable reference when instantiating the struct variable before changing the values:

```
let collection_info = &mut Account::<CollectionInfo>::try_from(&mut ctx.accounts.collection_info)?;
collection_info.version = CollectionInfo::VERSION;
```

You may also need to manually call the `Account::exit` function on the account after the mutations are complete because this `Account` is being created out-of-bound from the self-managing ones created via the `Context` struct:

```
collection_info.exit(&crate::ID)?;
```

Comment: That worked, Thanks a lot.